# Exchange 2010 VHD Corrupted But Is Not

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, corruption, virtual-disk

I am experiencing a strange problem with my Exchange 2010 server. The virtual disk holding all Exchange databases on the Exchange server is acting like it is corrupted. If I run chkdsk E: /F is says the file system is RAW, but when I take down the server and mount the disk in another 2008 VM, I can run CHKDSK with no errors at all.

I am going to try update the database locations in Exchange to point to a UNC path of the other server to at least get things moving again but obviously this is not a permanent fix.

Any ideas?

Saturday night, 1 week into my 2 week holiday. Typical.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried attaching another VHD to the machine? if that works, maybe you should create a new VHD for the DBs.

Comment: @EliadTech Appreciate the reply. No, I havent, but believe it or not I have just changed the drive letter from E to X on the Exchange server and I can now run CHKDSK on it with no errors. I am going to change back to E and reboot to see if solved. Otherwise I will need to update Exchange paths for the databases to use X. Any ideas how to do that? Cheers.

Comment: In the EMC, go to Organization > Mailbox > right click on a DB > Move.